# How do I add custom javascript to my rails3 views?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to add JavaScript to my Rails3 views?

I would like to be able to do some processing in a controller, then craft some JavaScript based on the result and put the resulting JavaScript in a view.

For example, I would like to get a series of lat/lng points from a database and create markers on a Google Map.  The map initialization and markers must be created in JavaScript, but interact with the view.  (This is just one example of what I am trying to accomplish. I am not looking for recommendations of gems/plugins that do Google Maps integration).

Is there some way to render an js.erb file into the head of a particular view?  What is the "rails way" of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the JavaScript before the page is loaded at all -- i.e. not through Ajax -- then there is no particular reason why you couldn't just create a `_javascript.html.erb` partial containing the script tags and then do the following in your view:

```
<%= render 'javascript' %>
```

The code in `_javascript.html.erb` would have access to the instance variables set in your controller, and you could write it the same way as a `.js.erb` file.

(Alternatively, you could use `<%= yield :head %>` in your layout file's `<head>` section and then `<content_for :head do %><%= render 'javascript' %><% end %>` in your views, if you want the script to be in the `<head>`.)

If you want to run the JavaScript on a page following an Ajax request, then just banging the code into your `my_action.js.erb` file and interpolating `<%= @my_instance_variable.value %>` as required will work -- the resulting code will be run on your page after the request finishes.